# How would I use Jackson to flatten JSON with nested array?

Tags: java, arrays, json, class, jackson

I am using JackSon to parse the following JSON:

```
{
    "AwardID": "1111111",
    "AwardTitle": "Test Title",
    "Effort": 
        "[
            {
                "PersonFirstName": "Jon",
                "PersonLastName": "Snow"
            }
        ]"
}
```

I would like to flatten this to be used in the following class:

```
public class Award {
    private String awardId;
    private String awardTitle;
    private String personFirstName;
    private String personLastName;
}
```

I have tried the following and have gotten the first two values, but I haven't been able to get the values from Effort trying to use [JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html).  I noted that it doesn't work with arrays, but I am trying the objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS, true) configuration in the main method used to get the values.

```
public class Award {
    @JsonProperty("AwardID")
    private String awardId;

    @JsonProperty("AwardTitle")
    private String awardTitle;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Effort effort;
}

public class Effort {
    private String personFirstName;
    private String personLastName;
}
```

Note that I only expect one value in the Effort array from the API response at this time.

What is recommended to try next?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is having a `List<Effort>` if you have a **JSON Array**.

If there is always 1 item for `Effort`, the returning JSON should not have `Effort` as a **JSON Array** and instead should be a **JSON Object**.

But if you can only handle it codewise, you can have something like this *(Note that there should always contain one item in Effort, otherwise it will throw Exception)*:

```java
public class Award {
    @JsonProperty("AwardID")
    private String awardId;

    @JsonProperty("AwardTitle")
    private String awardTitle;

    @JsonProperty("Effort")
    private Effort effort;
}

public class Effort {
    @JsonProperty("PersonFirstName")
    private String personFirstName;

    @JsonProperty("PersonLastName")
    private String personLastName;
}
```

And your `ObjectMapper` needs to be enabled with `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS` as well:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS);
Award award = mapper.readValue(rawJson, Award.class); // rawJson is your JSON String
```

And it should have the following output:

```
Award(awardId=1111111, awardTitle=Test Title, effort=Effort(personFirstName=Jon, personLastName=Snow))
```

Note that the annotation [`@JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) can only apply on **JSON Object**, not **JSON Array**:

> Value is serialized as JSON Object (can not unwrap JSON arrays using this mechanism)